# What is the format for specifying multiple tags to exclude from cvs2git

Tags: cvs2svn, cvs2git

I understand I can perform a conversion of a CVS repository to GIT excluding all NIGHTLY_XXXX build tags by doing the following

> cvs2git --exclude='NIGHTLY_.*' --blobfile=git-blob.dat
>   --dumpfile=git-dump.dat --username=dev /opt/mycvsrepository/mymodule

But what is the format of the command line arguments if I also want to remove more than 1 wildcard? i.e

"NIGHTLY_*" and "BETA_RELEASE_*" and "RC_*"

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a more complicated regular expression that matches all of the tag names that should be excluded, like

```
cvs2git --exclude='(NIGHTLY|BETA_RELEASE|RC)_.*' \
        --blobfile=git-blob.dat --dumpfile=git-dump.dat \
        --username=dev /opt/mycvsrepository/mymodule
```

But it is probably easier to use the `--exclude` option multiple times; e.g.,

```
cvs2git --exclude='NIGHTLY_.*' \
        --exclude='BETA_RELEASE_.*' \
        --exclude='RC_.*' \
        --blobfile=git-blob.dat --dumpfile=git-dump.dat \
        --username=dev /opt/mycvsrepository/mymodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question

but thanks to this amazing https://regex101.com/  site I realized I need to give it as a regular expression

so the format would be

> --exclude='(NIGHTLY_.* )|(BETA_RELEASE_.* )|(RC_.*)'